# How to access jOOQ generated Routine's field as value by using Custom Converter?

Tags: java, json, xml, plpgsql, jooq-codegen-maven

I'm having an issue with accessing field of generated Routine from **PL/pgSQL user-defined function** (which returns **JSON data type** as a result) already mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62535195/6805866) question.

This is my result of `get_all_orders()` function created in PL/pgSQL of JSON type:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "order_id": 1,
      "total_price": 29.99,
      "order_date": "2019-08-22T10:06:33",
      "user": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "username": "test"
      },
      "order_items": [
        {
          "order_item_id": 1,
          "amount": 1,
          "book": {
            "book_id": 1,
            "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
            "price": 29.99,
            "amount": 400,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "authors": [
              {
                "author_id": 4,
                "first_name": "JK",
                "last_name": "Rowling"
              }
            ],
            "categories": [
              {
                "category_id": 2,
                "name": "Lyric",
                "is_deleted": false
              }
            ]
          },
          "order_id": 1,
          "total_order_item_price": 29.99
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "order_id": 2,
      "total_price": 29.99,
      "order_date": "2019-08-22T10:10:13",
      "user": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "username": "test"
      },
      "order_items": [
        {
          "order_item_id": 2,
          "amount": 1,
          "book": {
            "book_id": 1,
            "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
            "price": 29.99,
            "amount": 400,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "authors": [
              {
                "author_id": 4,
                "first_name": "JK",
                "last_name": "Rowling"
              }
            ],
            "categories": [
              {
                "category_id": 2,
                "name": "Lyric",
                "is_deleted": false
              }
            ]
          },
          "order_id": 2,
          "total_order_item_price": 29.99
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access Routine as a Field by following [Custom data type bindings](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) manual and what I've managed to do so far is to create custom Converter in order to convert [org.jooq.JSON](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.13.x/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html) into [io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/):

```
public class JSONJsonObjectConverter implements Converter<JSON, JsonObject>{    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4773701755042752633L;

    @Override
    public JsonObject from(JSON jooqJson) {
        String strVal = (jooqJson == null ? null : jooqJson.toString());
        return strVal == null ? null : JsonObject.mapFrom(strVal);
    }

    @Override
    public JSON to(JsonObject vertxJson) {
        String strVal = (vertxJson == null ? null : vertxJson.toString());      
        return strVal == null ? null : JSON.valueOf(strVal);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JSON> fromType() {
        return JSON.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JsonObject> toType() {
        return JsonObject.class;
    }

}
```

...this is [link](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-shared/src/main/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/shared/internal/QueryResult.java) to QueryResult soruce code and I'm using this method to invoke it (Custom created Converter):

```
public static JsonObject convertGetAllOrdersQRToJsonObject(QueryResult qr) {
        //JsonArray ordersJA = qr.get("orders", JsonArray.class);
        DataType<JsonObject> jsonObjectType = SQLDataType.JSON.asConvertedDataType(new JSONJsonObjectConverter());
        //DataType<JsonArray> jsonArrayType = SQLDataType.JSONArray.asConvertedDataType(new JsonArrayConverter());
        DataType<JsonObject> jsonObjectTypeDefault = SQLDataType.JSON.asConvertedDataType((Binding<? super JSON, JsonObject>) new JsonObjectConverter());
        Field<JsonObject> ordersFieldDefault = DSL.field("get_all_orders", jsonObjectTypeDefault);
        Field<JsonObject> ordersField = DSL.field("get_all_orders", jsonObjectType);
        JsonObject orders = qr.get("orders", JsonObject.class);
        
//      return new JsonObject().put("orders", orders);
        return new JsonObject().put("orders", ordersField); // try ordersFieldDefault(.toString()) as value parameter
        
    }
```

I'm invoking above mentioned methods inside of following one:

```
Future<QueryResult> ordersFuture = queryExecutor.transaction(qe -> qe
            .query(dsl -> dsl
                .select(Routines.getAllOrders())
        ));                     
        LOGGER.info("Passed ordersFuture...");
        ordersFuture.onComplete(handler -> {
            if (handler.succeeded()) {                              
                QueryResult qRes = handler.result();                    
                JsonObject ordersJsonObject = OrderUtilHelper.convertGetAllOrdersQRToJsonObject(qRes);
                LOGGER.info("ordersJsonObject.encodePrettily(): " + ordersJsonObject.encodePrettily());
                resultHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(ordersJsonObject));
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Error, something failed in retrivening ALL orders! handler.cause() = " + handler.cause());
                queryExecutor.rollback();               
                resultHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(handler.cause()));
            }
        });
```

...and this is generated method in ***Routines.java class*** which is being used in **last mentioned code above** in expression that returns value into `dsl -> dsl.select(Routines.getAllOrders())` statement part:

```
/**
 * Convenience access to all stored procedures and functions in public
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class Routines {
/**
     * Get <code>public.get_all_orders</code> as a field.
     */
    public static Field<JSON> getAllOrders() {
        GetAllOrders f = new GetAllOrders();

        return f.asField();
    }
}
```

...and (finally) here is my `*.jooq.routines.GetAllOrders.java` class:

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class GetAllOrders extends AbstractRoutine<JSON> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 917599810;

    /**
     * The parameter <code>public.get_all_orders.RETURN_VALUE</code>.
     */
    public static final Parameter<JSON> RETURN_VALUE = Internal.createParameter("RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, false, false);

    /**
     * Create a new routine call instance
     */
    public GetAllOrders() {
        super("get_all_orders", Public.PUBLIC, org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON);

        setReturnParameter(RETURN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

BTW, Vertx library also uses [JsonArray](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonArray.html) class which is used to work with arrays but I don't see a way to map ALREADY generated org.jooq.JSON into `org.jooq.impl.JSONArray` and then into `io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray` type.

Is there I am missing something (I know I am dealing with **generated Routine**, but example given in jOOQ's manual **contains only Table field**)...or maybe I should've created [Custom Data Type Binding class](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/)?
Any suggestion/help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE1**:
I've followed instructions given in linked Q&A in comments and this is what I've added and have already of `<forcedType>`s in my `pom.xml` :

```
    <!-- Convert varchar column with name 'someJsonObject' to a io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject -->
    <forcedType>
        <userType>io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject</userType>
        <converter>io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.shared.JsonObjectConverter</converter>
        <includeExpression>someJsonObject</includeExpression>
        <includeTypes>.*</includeTypes>
        <nullability>ALL</nullability>
        <objectType>ALL</objectType>
    </forcedType>
    <!-- Convert varchar column with name 'someJsonArray' to a io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray -->
    <forcedType>
        <userType>io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray</userType>
        <converter>
            io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.shared.JsonArrayConverter</converter>
        <includeExpression>someJsonArray</includeExpression>
        <includeTypes>.*</includeTypes>
        <nullability>ALL</nullability>
        <objectType>ALL</objectType>
    </forcedType>
    <forcedType>
        <userType>io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject</userType>>
        <!-- also tried to use "org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)" 
and it did NOT work so I gave this custom created Conveter a try and it ALSO did NOT work! -->
        <converter>
            com.ns.vertx.pg.converters.JSONJsonObjectConverter.ofNullable(JSON.class, JsonObject.class, JsonObject::toString, JSON::valueOf)
        </converter>
        <includeExpression>(?i:get_all_orders|return_value)</includeExpressio>
    </forcedType>
```

...and when I do Maven> Update Project + check *Force Update of Snapshots/Releases* I get 32 overall following ERROR messages:

> JsonObject cannot be resolved

...and

> JsonObject cannot be resolved to a type

...and this is my generated `*.jooq.routines.GetAllOrders.java` class:

```
 // This class is generated by jOOQ.     
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class GetAllOrders extends AbstractRoutine<JsonObject> {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -431575258;

     // The parameter <code>public.get_all_orders.RETURN_VALUE</code>.         
    public static final Parameter<JsonObject> RETURN_VALUE = Internal.createParameter("RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, false, false, org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(JSON.class, JsonObject.class, JsonObject::toString, JSON::valueOf));
       
     //Create a new routine call instance
    public GetAllOrders() {
        super("get_all_orders", Public.PUBLIC, org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(JSON.class, JsonObject.class, JsonObject::toString, JSON::valueOf));

        setReturnParameter(RETURN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

I already have these programmaticly created converter for this generator [ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/blob/master/vertx-jooq-generate/src/main/java/io/github/jklingsporn/vertx/jooq/generate/classic/ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator.java) (more info about it avaliable [here](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-classic-reactive#maven-code-generator-configuration-example-for-postgres)) for `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` in 1st mentioned `<forcedType>`. Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE2**:
I've also tried to employ this `org.jooq.Converter` converter like this (had to use qualified refernce for JSON class otherwise it didn't perform imports in Generated Routine clases):

```
<forcedType>
    <userType>java.lang.String</userType>
    <converter>
        org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString,org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf)
    </converter>
    <includeExpression>(?i:get_all_orders|return_value)  </includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

...and I get this in generated GetAllOrders.java class:

```
 @SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public class GetAllOrders extends AbstractRoutine<String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1922028137;

         // The parameter <code>public.get_all_orders.RETURN_VALUE</code>.         
        public static final Parameter<String> RETURN_VALUE = Internal.createParameter("RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, false, false, org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString, org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf));    
// in above value I get ERROR "The method ofNullable(Class<T>, Class<U>, Function<? super T,? extends U>, Function<? super U,? extends T>) in the type Converter is not applicable for the arguments (Class<JSON>, Class<String>, Object::toString, org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf)"
// ... for org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(..) method + 23 same/similar ERRORS

         // Create a new routine call instance         
        public GetAllOrders() {
            super("get_all_orders", Public.PUBLIC, org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString, org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf));   
            setReturnParameter(RETURN_VALUE);
        }
    }
```

Since that did NOT work, I've tried to solve that problem by creating `JooqJsonConverter.java` **Custom Converter class** like this:

```
public class JooqJsonConverter implements Converter<String, JSON>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4773701755042752633L;

    @Override
    public JSON from(String jooqJson) { return jooqJson == null ? null : JSON.valueOf(jooqJson); }

    @Override
    public String to(JSON jooqJson) { return jooqJson == null ? null : jooqJson.toString(); }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() { return String.class; }

    @Override
    public Class<JSON> toType() { return JSON.class; }

}
```

...and changing Converter under  tag:

```
<converter>
    com.ns.vertx.pg.converters.JooqJsonConverter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString,org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf)
</converter>
```

...and I get same code GetAllOrders.java class with diffrence small difference

```
 public static final Parameter<String> RETURN_VALUE = Internal.createParameter("RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, false, false, com.ns.vertx.pg.converters.JooqJsonConverter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString, org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf));

    public GetAllOrders() {
        super("get_all_orders", Public.PUBLIC, org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.JSON, com.ns.vertx.pg.converters.JooqJsonConverter.ofNullable(org.jooq.JSON.class, String.class, Object::toString, org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf));
        setReturnParameter(RETURN_VALUE);
    }
```

...and ONLY this 8 errors (2 for each of 4 generated Routine classes):

> The method ofNullable(Class, Class, Object::toString,
> org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf) is undefined for the type
> JooqJsonConverter

Any idea what is missing/am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Have you applied your converter to your routine using a `<forcedType/>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557822/521799)

Comment: I've didn't come across any of those solutions in your comments, but I've tried it and it didn't work. I've updated my question under **UPDATE1** section, so please take a look.

Comment: I've also tried using same solution as you did in linked Q&A and then also creating my own Custom Converter and trying it out. Results can be seen in my **UPDATE2** section of my question. Please take a look.

Comment: So, in fact, using a `<forcedType/>` was the answer to your original question. It is usually a good idea to keep questions focused here on Stack Overflow, because future visitors will find them more useful if each question discusses only one problem. You can easily ask new, focused questions that discuss a different topic. As a bonus, you will get better, more focused answers. Win win :)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it appears that problems I'm having in my code are obviously contained of more sub-problems. Since this is the case I'll create one or more separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

[The first part of your question is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557822/521799). In your updates, this is not valid Java code:

```java
org.jooq.JSON.class::valueOf
```

You meant to write this:

```java
org.jooq.JSON::valueOf
```

Comment: Indeed, silly typo mistake made by copy-pasting code. I've managed to correct other ERRORS in jOOQ code-generation (by using TWO `<forcedType>` elements as you've suggested in linked Q&A of your answer) and ran into a new problem for creating proper converter for **function INPUT parameter type**. Therefore I've created a NEW [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601302/how-to-fix-generating-proper-value-type-for-input-parameter-in-jooq-for-generate?noredirect=1&lq=1). :) Please take a look.